# Returning the newly created string

Tags: php, string

I'm very new to php and I'm trying to concatenate three strings. And this works, if I do so:

```
echo Test::getBaseUrl() , '/' , $append_url;
```

But this happens inside the method and I wish to return this to the callee, but when I add `return` instead of `echo` like this:

```
return Test::getBaseUrl() , '/' , $append_url;
```

I get an error like this :

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/ubuntu/Test.php on line 31
```

Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: `echo "a", "b";` does **not** concatenate the two strings, it simply first output the first string, then output the second string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`echo` is a language construct and it supports a special syntax, that allows to chain several `echo`-"actions". This means

```
echo $a, $b;
```

is in fact

```
echo $a; echo $b;
```

(not really, it's a little bit different, but thats not important)

What you are *really* looking for is the concatenation

```
echo $a . $b;
```

which (because this is a regular operator) works with everything, that can handle a string

```
return $a . $b;
```

Answer (score 4):

use this `.` for concatenation in `PHP`

```
return Test::getBaseUrl() . '/' . $append_url;
```

As suggested by **Prisoner**

**additional: the reason it works for echo $x, $y, $z is because you can pass a comma list that essentially outputs multiple echo's (e.g. `echo $x; echo $y;`).**

Comment: additional: the reason it works for `echo $x, $y, $z` is because you can pass a comma list that essentially does the same thing as concatenation.

Comment: @Prisoner No :) Compare http://codepad.viper-7.com/ib5k62 and http://codepad.viper-7.com/NNNNFo "essential the same" would mean, that it behaves like a concatenation, but they both behave quite different: With `,` each statement is `echo`d on its own. If you use the concatenation `.` the concatenation is applied first and _then_ the resulting string is outputted.

Comment: @KingCrunch Fair, it does act more like multiple echo's as apposed to concatenation.

Comment: @Prisoner Exactly. The "real life" difference is, that when (for example) the last statement fails, the preceding strings will `echo`d nevertheless :) Oh, and thanks that you remove the "only for variables"-thing :D

Answer (score 2):

I don't think , is used for joining strings in any programming language.

In PHP, the concatenation operator (.)  is used to put two string values together.

```
echo Test::getBaseUrl() . '/' . $append_url;

return Test::getBaseUrl() . '/' . $append_url;
```

See : [PHP String](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_string.asp)

Answer (score 1):

PHP string concatenation uses a .

```
echo Test::getBaseUrl() . '/' . $append_url;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want comma in string:

```
 echo Test::getBaseUrl().','.'/'.', '.$append_url;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `echo Test::getBaseUrl() , '/' , $append_url;` you are actually saying

```
echo Test::getBaseUrl();
echo '/';
echo $append_url;
```

If you want to a create a single string, you have to concatenate the 3 string using the `.`
example:

```
return Test::getBaseUrl() . '/' . $append_url;
```

Answer (score 1):

All answers that contain the keywords *language construct* and *regular construct* are right on the money, but just to clarify a bit more:
Functions can't return more than **1** value nothing more (and nothing less... at some low level, a function *does* return some signal when it's finished. In other words, if `return` were a function it'd be defined something along the lines of:

```
function return($value)
{//written in PHP-style, obviously
    fwrite(php://stdout, $value, sizeof($value));
}
```

In short: a function that takes but one argument, so comma-separating a multitude of arguments simply doesn't work

Comment: Thanks that's a bit of additional info!